# Is there already support for XML Documentation inside TypeScript?

Tags: xml-documentation, typescript

Is there already support for XML Documentation inside TypeScript? It seems there isn't, but maybe I am overlooking something.

I'd like something like this:

```
export class Point {
   /// <summary>This is a Point class.</summary>

    constructor (public x: number, public y: number) { 
        /// <summary>Creates a new Point object</summary>
        /// <param name="x"></param>
        /// <param name="y"></param>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no mention of this in the language specification, so there is currently no support for this feature.

The only comment syntax in use is to create a dependency on a source file:

```
/// <reference path="..."/>
```

You can [suggest features such as this on the project page](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions) - so it could be added to the language in the future if the idea gains traction.

Comment: Thanks, added the feature request.

Comment: Is there a link to the feature request? I'd like to support it.

Comment: Here I posted the comment: typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/397660 Anders Hejlsberg wrote that they were aiming for JSDoc maybe instead of Xml Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently JSDoc is now supported, at least in Visual Studio Code, as I'm currently using it there and it shows in the intellisense popups.

Comment: Thanks, it's working for me in VSCode, and there's an official page on it here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JsDoc-support-in-JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, samples from Microsoft do include this style of comment.  From the Parallax sample:

```
    constructor(scrollableContent: HTMLElement, perspective: number) {
        /// <param name="scrollableContent">The container that will be parallaxed.</param>
        /// <param name="perspective">The ratio of how much back content should be 
        /// scrolled relative to forward content.  For example, if this value is 
        /// 0.5, and there are 2 surfaces, the front-most surface would be scrolled 
        /// normally, and the surface behind it would be scrolled half as much.</param>
        this.perspective = perspective;
        this.surface = [];
        this.content = scrollableContent;

        $(scrollableContent).scroll((event: JQueryEventObject) => {
            this.onContainerScroll(event);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I added a comment on codeplex and the reply of Anders Hejlsberg was that they were leaning towards JsDoc. http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/397660